# HTML/PHP Email Form just sending one word

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

None of the other questions have resolved my problem. The problem is: I have an html email form, with php, when I click submit to test it sends, but it only sends one word , and that word is: **From**. (they are all in the same *email.php* file). Here is the form alone:
*PHP:*

```
    <?php

    if($_POST["message"]) {
                
        mail("my email", "Feedback for website",
                    
        $_POST["$message"]. "From: $email");
                
    }
                
?>
```

*HTML*/JS:

```
<form method="post">
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Bill Gates" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" required/>
                
                <h2>Email</h2>
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Big-Gates@thesam.co.nz" alt="try loading page again." autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" name="email" required/>
                <h2>Feedback:</h2>
                <textarea name="message" required></textarea><br>
                
                <button type="submit" onclick="completeFunc()">Submit</button>
            
            </form>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `$_POST["$message"]` should be `$_POST["message"]`, and you're not setting the value of `$email`.

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting _now_.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong word in the PHP code.

Wrong:

```
<?php
   if($_POST["message"]) {
       mail("my email", "Feedback for website",
       $_POST["$message"]. "From: $email");
   }
?>
```

Correct:

```
<?php
   if($_POST["message"]) {
       mail("my email", "Feedback for website",
       $_POST["message"]. "From: $email");
   }
?>
```

Difference: You're using `$_POST["$message"]` but it should be `$_POST["message"]`.

Comment: I'm bad.. so if I want to post email do I go: ```$_POST["$message"]``` and then in html set the "name" element to email? Sorry I'm kinda bad